# How long does Twilio store chat history?

Tags: web, twilio, chat

I've been browsing Twilio's docs and API reference but I was unable to find how long does the chat history is stored.

I don't have any own DB for storing messages as well as I don't have any other logic on my backend related to chat. I'm using Twilio to handle everything for me. I'm only using their client SDKs to interact.

Can anyone help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried talking to twilio support?

Comment: Yes, I emailed them 2 days ago and I've received no response since then. I'm sure I'll get it somewhere soon but I don't want to waste time meanwhile and chat history on my project would be #1 criteria to choose chat SDK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

My apologies for the delay from support getting back to you, but the good news is I have an answer for you.

At Twilio we store everything forever until you either:

1. Close your account
2. Delete the messages or channels yourself
3. Delete the entire service instance

So not fetching that from a database is the right choice in my opinion as it would potentially just add extra latency and logic into your code.

Hope this help yoiu.